# docker: create a mongodb volume that is still saved after docker-compose down?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, persistence, docker-volume

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  pokerstats:
    image: pokerstats
    container_name: pokerstats
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on: 
      - db
  db:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./database:/data
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: pokerstats
```

My issue is that when I run `docker-compose down` all the data within my mongo database is lost.

How can I create a mongo volume that persists even when the mongo container goes down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) the database volume needs to be `/data/db`. This is also seen in [the Dockerfile volume](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/d688c16b4520f3a86d343843855fe8ea6b6f4539/4.2/Dockerfile#L100).

Since the volume is defined in the Dockerfile, if you do not create a volume at that directory, even if you created a volume in the parent like `/data`, docker will create an anonymous volume at `/data/db` which will show up as a long guid volume name in `docker volume ls`. Depending on how the container is run, those may be left behind.

Therefore the fix is to adjust your volume mount to that path:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  pokerstats:
    image: pokerstats
    container_name: pokerstats
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on: 
      - db

  db:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./database:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: pokerstats
```

Note that unless you need direct access to this data on the host, I'd recommend using a named volume instead. It includes initialization steps that helps with permission issues you may encounter with host volumes, particularly when running directly on a Linux host.

---

To use a named volume, that would look like:

```yaml
version: "3"
    
services:

  pokerstats:
    image: pokerstats
    container_name: pokerstats
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on: 
      - db

  db:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: pokerstats
volumes:
    dbdata:
```

Comment: When I do this I get an error in my mongo log: Fatal Assertion 28595 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 860

Comment: @java12399900 Was that with a named or host volume? Assuming you're still on host volumes, if you haven't already, I'd make sure `./database` is empty before starting. You likely have some random files in there from previous runs. Beyond that, did this solve the db persistence? If so, then you've moved on to a new issue.

Comment: All I have done is change to - ./database:/data/db in my compose file - but now as long as I do docker-compose up -d the mongo container stops again with the error shown above so it has not solved either issue

Comment: @java12399900 if you haven't tried either of the other recommendations above, I'd recommend trying those. Mainly deleting content from `database` from when you mounted other directories there, and switching to a named volume instead of a host mount to eliminate permission issues.

Comment: I have also deleted the database folder and it does not make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `volumes` for MongoDb container:

```
volumes:
  - "./database:/data/db"
```

Comment: Thanks .  What difference do the quotes make?

Comment: @java12399900 Not only quotes, also `/data/db` path. In our production we've configured this way and it works :D

Comment: Its not the quotes. its the mount directory name which is important .`/data/db`